# Caching DbContext.Entry(entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have the following code in a "repository":

```
 if (DbContext.Entry(item) == null || DbContext.Entry(item).State == EntityState.Detached)
 {
     DbContext.Set<T>().Attach(item);
     DbContext.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
 }
```

It uses `DbContext.Entry(item)` three times to check if an entity should be considered modified.
Now, `DbContext.Entry(item)` is very slow, especially when calling it several hundreds of times, so I'm thinking to cache the entry:

```
var dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(item);
if (dbEntityEntry == null || dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Detached)
{
     DbContext.Set<T>().Attach(item);
     dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

This change makes the whole code some 50% faster, according to the profiler.
But I see in the EF source code that a new instance of DbEntityEntry is created on the call to .Entry().

```
public DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
     RuntimeFailureMethods.Requires((object) entity != null, (string) null, "entity != null");
     return new DbEntityEntry<TEntity>(new InternalEntityEntry(this.InternalContext, (object) entity));
}
```

So my question is, is it a good practice to call Entry() each time?
Or is it better to cache it, even when it doesn't have a performance impact?

The EF version that i'm using is 4.3.1.

Later:

I made a mockup project with EF 6.2.0, where I'm using two methods, Save, with cached DbEntityEntry, and SaveSlow, without cached.

EF 6.2.0

Created 1000 items in 00h:00m:00s.10ms

Called Save for 1000 items in 00h:00m:21s.82ms

Created 1000 items in 00h:00m:00s.06ms

Called SaveSlow for 1000 items in 00h:00m:25s.18ms

EF 4.3.1

Created 1000 items in 00h:00m:00s.09ms

Called Save for 1000 items in 00h:00m:48s.21ms

Created 1000 items in 00h:00m:00s.06ms

Called SaveSlow for 1000 items in 00h:01m:00s.20ms

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade your EF version?

Comment: Not too soon. The upgrade is on the agenda, but without a specific date.

Comment: You could try to make a test case with the newer version and see how they compare performance wise. That might get you a specific date for the upgrade ;). I'm not very familiar with version 4.3.1. but generaly speaking performance in EF went up from version 5.

Comment: If you're calling it hundreds of times, isn't it better to use a stateful context rather than stateless.?